# Passing data from EditText to TextView in another activity and savaing it with Shared Preferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have two activities, let's name them Activity A and Activity B.

Activity A contains EditText and RadioButton elements that user has to select and input something that will then be passed in Activity B that will display that text in it's own Text Views.

That all works like a charm, the **only problem is when I try to save data with SharedPreferences that I can't get working**. Tried with every tutorial I could find on Internet, but none of them worked.

Anyway, here's the code of Activity A:

```
public class StatistikeInputMain extends AppCompatActivity {
    RadioGroup radioGrupa;
    RadioButton imperial, metric;
    EditText visinaCM, visinaFT, visinaINC, tezina , bodyfat, tdee, bmi, bmr, ffmi;
    TextView rezultatTDEE, textVisinaCM, textVisinaFI, rezultatTezina, rezultatBMI, rezultatFFMI, rezultatBMR, rezultatBF;
    Button spremiRezultat;
    int onStartCount = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_statistike_input_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            String inputi = savedInstanceState.getString("INPUTI");
            tdee.setText(inputi);
        }

        onStartCount = 1;
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_left,
                    R.anim.anim_slide_out_left);
        } else {
            onStartCount = 2;
        }


// RADIO
        radioGrupa = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGrupaStatistike);
        imperial = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioStatistikeImperial);
        metric = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioStatistikeMetric);
//VISINA
        visinaCM = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStatistikeVisinaCM);
        visinaFT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStatistikeVisinaFEET);
        visinaINC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStatistikeVisinaINCH);
//TEŽINA
        tezina = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStatistikeTezina);
//BODYFAT
        bodyfat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStatistikeBF);
//TDEE
        tdee = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStatistikeTDEE);
//BMI
        bmi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStatistikeBMI);
//BMR
        bmr = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStatistikeBMR);
//FFMI
        ffmi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStatistikeFFMI);
//BUTTON
        spremiRezultat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStatistikeInputSpremi);
//REZULTATI
        rezultatTDEE = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatTDEE);
        textVisinaCM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatVisina);
        textVisinaFI = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeVisinaFeetInch);
        rezultatTezina = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatTezina);
        rezultatBMI = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeBMI);
        rezultatBMR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeBMR);
        rezultatFFMI = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeFFMI);
        rezultatBF = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatBodyFat);


    }

    public void radioStatistikeInputMetric(View view){
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.radioStatistikeMetric:
                if (checked)
                    // TU OVO SREDI!!!
                    //textVisinaCM.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    // visinaCM.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //textVisinaFI.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //visinaFT.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    // visinaINC.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                    spremiRezultat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AppLayoutMain.class);
                            intent.putExtra("tdeeInput", tdee.getText().toString());
                            intent.putExtra("bodyFatInput", bodyfat.getText().toString());
                            intent.putExtra("tezinaMetricInput", tezina.getText().toString());
                            intent.putExtra("visinaMetricInput", visinaCM.getText().toString());
                            intent.putExtra("bmiInput", bmi.getText().toString());
                            intent.putExtra("bmrInput", bmr.getText().toString());
                            intent.putExtra("ffmiInput", ffmi.getText().toString());
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                break;
        }
    }

    public void radioStatistikeInputImperial(View view){
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.radioStatistikeImperial:
                if (checked)
                    //textVisinaCM.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    // visinaCM.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //  textVisinaFI.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //   visinaFT.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //   visinaINC.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    spremiRezultat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AppLayoutMain.class);
                            intent.putExtra("tdeeInput", tdee.getText().toString());
                            intent.putExtra("bodyFatInput", bodyfat.getText().toString());
                            intent.putExtra("tezinaImperialInput", tezina.getText().toString());
                            intent.putExtra("visinaImperialInputFT", visinaFT.getText().toString());
                            intent.putExtra("visinaImperialInputINC", visinaINC.getText().toString());
                            intent.putExtra("bmiInput", bmi.getText().toString());
                            intent.putExtra("bmrInput", bmr.getText().toString());
                            intent.putExtra("ffmiInput", ffmi.getText().toString());
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    });
                break;
        }
    }
```

As you can see, results displayed in Activity B will depend on user selection, primary on selection of RadioButton (I think that there's the problem).

And here's the code of Activity B:

```
public class AppLayoutMain extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    int onStartCount = 0;
    ProgressDialog progress;
    NavigationView nvDrawer;
    DrawerLayout dlDrawer;
    android.support.v7.widget.CardView karticaStatistike;
    TextView tdeeRezultat, bodyFatRezultat, bmiRezultat, bmrRezultat, ffmiRezultat, tezinaMetricRezultat, visinaMetricRezultat, tezinaImperialRezultat, visinaFTImperialRezultat, visinaINCImperialRezultat, ciljTreningRezultat, razinaTreningRezultat, preporukaTreningRezultat, oneRMPotisakSKlupeRezultat, oneRMCucanjRezultat, oneRMMrtvoDizanjeRezultat, ciljPrehranaRezultat;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_layout_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        karticaStatistike = (android.support.v7.widget.CardView) findViewById(R.id.Statiske);


        //  STATISTIKE - PASSAN DATA

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String tdee = intent.getStringExtra("tdeeInput");
        String bf = intent.getStringExtra("bodyFatInput");
        String bmi = intent.getStringExtra("bmiInput");
        String bmr = intent.getStringExtra("bmrInput");
        String ffmi = intent.getStringExtra("ffmiInput");
        String tezinaMetric = intent.getStringExtra("tezinaMetricInput");
        String visinaMetric = intent.getStringExtra("visinaMetricInput");
        String tezinaImperial = intent.getStringExtra("tezinaImperialInput");
        String visinaImperial1 = intent.getStringExtra("visinaImperialInputFT");
        String visinaImperial2 = intent.getStringExtra("visinaImperialInputINC");
        tdeeRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatTDEE);
        tdeeRezultat.setText(tdee);
        bodyFatRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatBodyFat);
        bodyFatRezultat.setText(bf);
        bmiRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeBMI);
        bmiRezultat.setText(bmi);
        bmrRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeBMR);
        bmrRezultat.setText(bmr);
        ffmiRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeFFMI);
        ffmiRezultat.setText(ffmi);
        tezinaMetricRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatTezina);
        tezinaMetricRezultat.setText(tezinaMetric);
        visinaMetricRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatVisina);
        visinaMetricRezultat.setText(visinaMetric);



// SMISLI ŠTA ĆEŠ S OVIM, IZAZIVA KONFLIKT U VISINI I TEŽINI, PROBAJ S NEKIM IFOM
       // tezinaImperialRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatTezina);
       // tezinaImperialRezultat.setText(tezinaImperial);
        //visinaFTImperialRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatVisina);
        //visinaFTImperialRezultat.setText(visinaImperial1 + "'" +  " " + visinaImperial2 + "''");
        //  STATISTIKE - KRAJ PASSANJA



// TRENING - PASSAN DATA
        String oneRMBench = intent.getStringExtra("oneRMBenchInput");
        String oneRMSquat = intent.getStringExtra("oneRMSquatInput");
        String oneRMDead = intent.getStringExtra("oneRMDeadInput");
        String ciljTreninga = intent.getStringExtra("vrijednostSpinneraCilj");
        String razinaIskustva = intent.getStringExtra("vrijednostSpinneraRazinaIskustva");

        oneRMPotisakSKlupeRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTreningRezultat1RMPotisakSKlupe);
        oneRMPotisakSKlupeRezultat.setText(oneRMBench);
        oneRMCucanjRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTreningRezultat1RMCucanj);
        oneRMCucanjRezultat.setText(oneRMSquat);
        oneRMMrtvoDizanjeRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTreningRezultat1RMMrtvoDizanje);
        oneRMMrtvoDizanjeRezultat.setText(oneRMDead);

        ciljTreningRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTreningRezultatCilj);
        ciljTreningRezultat.setText(ciljTreninga);
        razinaTreningRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTreningRezultatRazinaIskustva);
        razinaTreningRezultat.setText(razinaIskustva);


// PREHRANA - PASSAN DATA

        String prehrana = intent.getStringExtra("vrijednostSpinnera");

        ciljPrehranaRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPrehranaCiljRezultat);
        ciljPrehranaRezultat.setText(prehrana);
        tdeeRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewPrehranaTDEE);
        tdeeRezultat.setText(tdee);
```

I didn't paste all of the code here, just the relevant part.

I don't know what to do, I deleted all of the text that had anything with SharedPreferences because it wasn't working, so if anyone could walk me through this I would appreciate it!!

I did it like you say, but still won't save data.. Here's what I did:

Activity A:

```
    SharedPreferences preference;

// IN ONCREATE
preference = getSharedPreferences("STATE", MODE_PRIVATE);
                            preference.edit().putString("tdeeInput", tdee.getText().toString()).commit();
```

Activity B:

```
            SharedPreferences preference;

// IN ONCREATE
      preference = getSharedPreferences("STATE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            tdee = preference.getString("tdeeInput", null);
```

In Activity B that `tdee` should save the result ov `tdeeRezultat` which you can find in code of Activity B that I initially posted. Can't set `tdee` to `tdeeRezultat` because it's not compatible type. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In your onClick function add

```
preference = getSharedPreferences("STATE", MODE_PRIVATE);
            preference.edit().putString(key, value).commit();
```

and in your second activity simply call

```
preference = getSharedPreferences("STATE",
                            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            email = preference.getString("yourkey", null);
```

Comment: you have to this  preference = getSharedPreferences("STATE", MODE_PRIVATE);
            preference.edit().putString(key, value).commit();    in onclick of activity a and this one preference = getSharedPreferences("STATE",
                            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            email = preference.getString("yourkey", null);  in oncreate of activity b

Answer (score 0):

-- SOLVED! --

Activity A:

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPreferencesFile";

//And in buttons onClick

spremiRezultat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                            editor.putString("tdeeSave", tdee.getText().toString());
                            editor.putString("bodyfatSave", bodyfat.getText().toString());
                            editor.putString("tezinaMetricSave", tezina.getText().toString());
                            editor.putString("visinaMetricSave", visinaCM.getText().toString());
                            editor.putString("bmiSave", bmi.getText().toString());
                            editor.putString("bmrSave", bmr.getText().toString());
                            editor.putString("ffmiSave", ffmi.getText().toString());
                            editor.commit();
```

Activity B:

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPreferencesFile";

//In onCreate

 tdeeRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatTDEE);
        tdeeRezultat.setText(settings.getString("tdeeSave", "..."));
        bodyFatRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatBodyFat);
        bodyFatRezultat.setText(settings.getString("bodyfatSave", "..."));
        bmiRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeBMI);
        bmiRezultat.setText(settings.getString("bmiSave", "..."));
        bmrRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeBMR);
        bmrRezultat.setText(settings.getString("bmrSave", "..."));
        ffmiRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeFFMI);
        ffmiRezultat.setText(settings.getString("ffmiSave", "..."));
        tezinaMetricRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatTezina);
        tezinaMetricRezultat.setText(settings.getString("tezinaMetricSave", "..."));
        visinaMetricRezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewStatistikeRezultatVisina);
        visinaMetricRezultat.setText(settings.getString("visinaMetricSave", "..."));
```